# Eclipse PDT Variable $this is undefined

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Sorry if this have been asked before. I have searched but not found any answers.

I installed Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) for PHP developers and created a project from existing folder.

I noticed that when I opened index.php that variable $this is undefined:

[image: variable $this is undefined]

This happens everywhere in my project. Also in the .phtml (view) files.

[image: variable $this is undefined]

I am quite new to Eclipse and I couldn't find anything in the settings.

Does anyone know how to remove the warning and fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: try adding this on the top of your page
 global $this;

Comment: Well this is not a PHP warning per say. It's just Eclipse who have decided that this is a warning. I have had Eclipse installations on other computer where this wasn't there. It's just started to appear on new installations on new computers. Really veird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1094029&goto=1791984&#msg_1791984) on the Eclipse forum, which worked for me. Instead of disabling the undefined variables, I just had to add:

```php
/** @var Type $this */
```

to my file and it no longer shows up as a warning. After review of a project in update PDT and PHP version, I had to change it to:

```php
/** @var mixed $this */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable notification about undefined variables. 
Go into window->prefences->php->validation->errors/warnings and set option "ignore" in undefined variable row. 
After that DTLC index will be refrashed and underlines will disappear.

Comment: Can we fix this warning/error by making setup level changes into Eclipse?